# How to implement abstract classes from a Enhanced Entity-Relationship model?

Tags: sql, mysqli, entity-relationship

i want to implement this relationship on a mySQL database.
[image: Relationship where a entity called Person is superclass from Student and Teacher classes on a a total and disjunt espetialization]

I'm using this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(40),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Student
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(id)
    REFERENCES Person(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Teacher
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
room INTEGER NOT NULL,    
FOREIGN KEY(id)
    REFERENCES Person(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

This way i can guarantee that will not exist a Teacher or Student that isn't a Person, however i cannot guarantee "total" especialization. May exist a Person that isn't Student or Teacher. Moreover, i cannot guarantee exclusivity. May exist a Person that is Student AND Teacher.

How can i solve this in a Relational database as MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

re "May exist a Person that isn't Student or Teacher": If you are storing history, this is quite valid; once a Student graduates, or a Teacher retires or joins another organization, the records will stilll need to exist in the database for at least a period of time..

re "May exist a Person that isn't Student or Teacher": This also is a legitimate circumstance. At universities many (most? all?) Teaching Assistants are also graduate students.